# True or False $W_i\cap \Sigma_{i\neq j}W_j=\Sigma_{i\neq j}( W_i\cap W_j)=\cap W_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following true?

For vector spaces $W_1,...,W_m$

$$ W_i\cap \Sigma_{i\neq j}W_j=\Sigma_{i\neq j}( W_i\cap W_j)=\cap W_i $$

Thank you.

Edit:

I'm trying to prove that if $V=\Sigma_{i}W_i$ and zero  vector of $V$ has a unique representation of vectors of  $W_i$, then  $W_i\cap \Sigma_{i\neq j}W_j=\{0\}$

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $W_1 = < (1,0) >, W_2 = < (0, 1) >, W_3 = < (1,1)>$. Then $W_2 + W_3 = \mathbb{R}^2$, and so $$W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3) = W_1$$but $$\cap W_i = 0$$